# Spinning up a mini-server in Electron

Tags: electron

I need to use cookies with Electron, but it runs on file:// and as it turns out, Chromium doesn't support local cookies.

So I need to spin up a little http server in order to save the session cookies. I need to authenticate with my API and save the cookie so that I can make queries to the API.

I've found a few resources to do this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/electronify-server
https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express

And I've been searching all over the internet, but I can't seem to get a solution working. :(

I have an angular app on top of Electron. So I will try to include as much information as I can.

main.js - http://pastebin.com/bnBtBTbm

script.js - http://pastebin.com/x7K8VzEW

File Structure -

[image]

I am trying to keep this app as simple as possible. I am not sure what I need in order to get this running on localhost instead of file:// - so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why specifically you need cookies? Most of the time plain old localstorage will work better in Electron. That being said, you did mention Angular, which does prefer to be served.

I simplified a basic HTTP server I use in one of my Electron apps. You will need to `npm install mime`, but everything else is built in.

```
var app = require('app');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var mime = require('mime');

function handleRequest(req, res) {
    var file = path.join(app.getAppPath(), req.url);

    fs.exists(file, function(exists) {
        if (exists && fs.lstatSync(file).isFile()) {
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", mime.lookup(file));
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            });
            fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res);

            return;
        }

        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write('404 Not Found');
        res.end();
    });
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(8888, function() {
    console.log('server started at http://localhost:8888');
});
```

Note that this will server your entire Electron app. You may want to change it to only serve a specific directory.

Also note that I did not test this after modification and if it works at all, it may not handle all cases. ;)

Comment: Testing it now! :) I'll post an update after I've tried implementing it! Thanks! As far as cookies go, I'm collaborating with OpenBMC - their REST API is sending back an authentication cookie that I need to use in order to be able to make additional queries after logging in. And because Electron uses Chromium, it doesn't support local cookies: e.g. file:/// - so I need to run my app on an http:// protocol instead. If this triggers any other ideas, please let me know! I've never been in this situation before, so I'm not 100% sure if I'm even asking the right question.

Comment: Okay, so it works! :) But, it's still running on localhost. I think I need 127.0.0.1 - is there any way to make this work?

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with using localhost. Unless it's not working for some reason?

Comment: The whole reason I'm spinning up a server is because I need to use cookies that I receive in the header from an API response. Chromium doesn't allow that. :( So I'm trying to figure that out.